# Font size for Telerik dropdown being overwritten

Tags: html, css

I am using Telerik UI for dropdowns and other UI elements. For some reason, my dropdown text size is being overwritten as 10px. I cannot figure out what is causing it.

Here is how it displays in browser:

[image]

Checking out the computed styles for the element, it says it is 10 px.
[image]

But nothing below the element says 10 px. I don't understand where the 10 px is coming from. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: The font size of `1rem` refers to the font size for the root element (HTML). Since it is 1 rem, that means it uses 1 times the root element font size. You can see that your html element has the font size defined as 62.5%. For most browsers the default font size is 16px, so 16 times 0.625 is 10px.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @JackA. Please add below and I will accept as Answer. Saved me banging my head against the wall for the rest of the afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font size of 1rem refers to the font size for the root element (HTML). Since it is 1 rem, that means it uses 1 times the root element font size. You can see that your html element has the font size defined as 62.5%. For most browsers the default font size is 16px, so 16 times 0.625 is 10px

Here's a helpful article on rem units in CSS: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/